# Latex Column chart

Tags: latex, tikz, pgf

Trying to create a latex column chart with single values in 3 different columns having 3 colors.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=Accuracy,
enlargelimits=0.05,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar interval=0.7,]
\addplot 
 coordinates {(1930,80)};
\addplot 
  coordinates {(1930,80)};
\addplot 
coordinates {(1930,80)};
\legend{Far,Near,Here}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a ybar size (e.g., `ybar=5pt`) and remove the `ybar interval` parameter, which looks bogus:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar=5pt,
        ylabel=Accuracy,
        xtick=data,
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        enlargelimits=0.05,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(1930,80)};
        \addplot coordinates {(1930,80)};
        \addplot coordinates {(1930,80)};
        \legend{Far,Near,Here}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: how to add a gap between the plots

Comment: You can add a gap between bars using the `ybar` parameter. I updated the answer with an example of `5pt`.